# Environment.getExternalStorageDerictory() return path to internal memory

Tags: android

Help me, please. My problem:
I have path /storage/sdcard0. It's internal memory on my device.
/storage/sdcard1 - path to SD.
Functoin

> Environment.getExternalStorageDerictory()

return path /storage/sdcard0. How can I get path to my SD?

Comment: "It's internal memory on my device" -- that is still [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) from the standpoint of the OS and the Android SDK. "How can I get path to my SD? " -- on Android 4.4+, you can get access to certain directories that are associated with your app that are on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

will return the primary external storage.

If you want to get the removable sd card path, you can read the /proc/mounts file to get the mounted medias since the path may vary from each device.

You can read this to get an idea :
[How to use your external removable SD Card](http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2014/09/28/xamarin-and-android-how-to-use-your-external-removable-sd-card/)